# Dependency injection with services and repositories in a web API in Golang

Tags: go, dependency-injection, backend

I'm working on a back-end API where I need to use some kind of DI. This is the "smartest" approach I've come up. From a general point of view, I don't think this is a bad approach whatsoever, but I'd like to know what your thoughts are on this. Do you use a similar approach o something better/simpler? What other options would you use? What implications do you think this might have in future?

This is what I've done so far:

```golang
// routes.go
package main

import (
  "xyz/handler"
  "xyz/pool"
)

func startRoutes(...) {
  var usersHandler = handler.NewUsersHandler(pool.Services().Users())
  var adminsHandler = handler.NewAdminsHandler(pool.Services().Admins())
  var groupsHandler = handler.NewGroupsHandler(pool.Services().Groups())
  /* ... */
}
```

```golang
// pool/pool.go
package pool

import (
  "xyz/database"
  "xyz/repository"
  "xyz/service"
  "sync"
)

type RepositoriesPool interface {
  Users() repository.UsersRepository
  Admins() repository.AdminsRepository
  Groups() repository.GroupsRepository
  Lists() repository.ListsRepository
  Tasks() repository.TasksRepository
  Steps() repository.StepsRepository
  Attachments() repository.AttachmentsRepository
  Settings() repository.SettingsRepository
  Another() repository.AnotherRepository
}

type repositoriesPoolImpl struct {
  users       repository.UsersRepository
  admins      repository.AdminsRepository
  groups      repository.GroupsRepository
  lists       repository.ListsRepository
  tasks       repository.TasksRepository
  steps       repository.StepsRepository
  attachments repository.AttachmentsRepository
  settings    repository.SettingsRepository
  another     repository.AnotherRepository
}

func (p repositoriesPoolImpl) Users() repository.UsersRepository {
  return p.users
}

func (p repositoriesPoolImpl) Admins() repository.AdminsRepository {
  return p.admins
}

func (p repositoriesPoolImpl) Groups() repository.GroupsRepository {
  return p.groups
}

/* ... */

var (
  rOnce sync.Once
  r     RepositoriesPool
)

func Repositories() RepositoriesPool {
  if nil == r {
    rOnce.Do(func() {
      var db = database.Get()
      r = &repositoriesPoolImpl{
        users:  repository.NewUsersRepository(db),
        admins: repository.NewAdminsRepository(db),
        groups: repository.NewGroupsRepository(db),
        /* ... */,
      }
    })
  }
  return r
}

type ServicesPool interface {
  Users() service.UsersService
  Admins() service.AdminsService
  Groups() service.GroupsService
  Lists() service.ListsService
  Tasks() service.TasksService
  Steps() service.StepsService
  Attachments() service.AttachmentsService
  Settings() service.SettingsService
  Another() service.AnotherService
}

type servicesPoolImpl struct {
  users       service.UsersService
  admins      service.AdminsService
  groups      service.GroupsService
  lists       service.ListsService
  tasks       service.TasksService
  steps       service.StepsService
  attachments service.AttachmentsService
  settings    service.SettingsService
  another     service.AnotherService
}

func (p servicesPoolImpl) Users() service.UsersService {
  return p.users
}

func (p servicesPoolImpl) Admins() service.AdminsService {
  return p.admins
}

func (p servicesPoolImpl) Groups() service.GroupsService {
  return p.groups
}

/* ... */

var (
  sOnce sync.Once
  s     *servicesPoolImpl
)

func Services() ServicesPool {
  if nil == s {
    sOnce.Do(func() {
      var usersService = service.NewUsersService(Repositories().Users())
      var adminsService = service.NewAdminsService(Repositories().Admins(), usersService)
      var groupsService = service.NewGroupsService(Repositories().Groups(), usersService, adminsService)
      s = &servicesPoolImpl{
        users:  usersService,
        admins: adminsService,
        groups: groupsService,
        /* ... */
      }
    })
  }
  return s
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a valid question for StackOverflow, as there's one definitive correct answer to this. Maybe you could try posting this question on Reddit instead.

Comment: Checking if `nil == s` can actually be racy if there are multiple goroutines. `sOnce.Do` is enough. That said, what makes you think you need a DI? Do you have multiple implementations of those interfaces? A simpler approach is to wire the application in main. It is much more straight forward, allows you to focus on the actual application rather than the plumbing.

Comment: @BurakSerdar the only place where I implement those interfaces is at `pool/pool.go`. I need DI for cases like `service.NewGroupsService(...)`. The main approach is simpler, I know, but I was trying to apply some separation of concerns, as you see I had a `routes.go` file. Would you even add routes in main?

Comment: @EliDavis yeah, I think I don't have enough karma to post as it says "Sorry, this post was removed by Reddit’s filters.", idk